# Set permission to DB

Tags: sql

Is there any possibilities to make a Db private in sql server 2005.
I mean only one user must can access and edit the others should not view and edit..

Comment: If yes ..Pls let me know about it

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own question instead of _editing_ it and adding details to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose who can edit and log on the database of course. You actually choose this while creating the databsae by choosing a username and password and you can add or remove users later as long as you are the administrator. Make sure yo choose SQL Server Authentication not Windows.

Comment: Other user (not for sa account) can do like this ..Then how to set password in ssms

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the users and logins and permissions.

Start [here](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/721441/Microsoft-SQL-Servers-Security-Model.htm).

- on the sql server create a login. this can can one of two types either a windows account or a sql account
- in the database map that login to a user. Give that user all the permission they need
- remove all the other uers or deny them the permissions

Comment: Can I do this for sa account ..deny access for sa account is possible..??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the obvious and mentioned security settings available, you can also set the database in [Single-user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx) and reduce your surface area by turning off access to TCP/IP via the [Surface Area Configuration Tool](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3496511/Managing-the-Surface-Area-of-SQL-Server-2005.htm).